# How to periodically switch on and switch off flashlight with 1kHz rate on rooted Redmi Note 5 Oro?

Tags: automation, scripts, flashlight

My objective is to write a shell script to periodically turn off and on my phone's flashlight (about 1 kHz or 500Hz). My phone is rooted. So I gained superuser shell access (#)

These are the files under my `sys/class/leds/flashlight`

```
whyred:/sys/class/leds/flashlight # ls
brightness device max_brightness power subsystem trigger uevent
```

<sup>([Original screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKwvu.png))</sup>

I was able to modify the content of the `brightness` file and was able to manually switch off and on my flashlight. However, I want to periodically switch on and off with a delay and for that, I need a timer trigger. But within the `trigger` file above, there is no delay section indicated. There was just some contents within the file (no numbers)

```
whyred:/sys/class/leds/flashlight # cat trigger
[none] bkl-trigger switch0_trigger flash0_trigger flash1_trigger torch0_trigger torch1_trigger switch1_trigger flash2_trigger torch2_trigger dc-online usb-online main-online pc_port-online battery-charging-or-full battery-charging battery-full battery-charging-blink-full-solid rfkill0 mmc0 mmc1 bms-online parallel-online rfkill1
```

<sup>([Original screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK554.png))</sup>

I was able to clock into a period of about 1-3ms by writing a bash script, that echoes brightness 100 followed by sleep and then echoes 0 brightness

Script:

```
while [ 1 le 100]
do
echo "100" > ~/sys/class/leds/brightness  
sleep(0.001)  
echo "100" > ~/sys/class/leds/brightness)
sleep(0.001)
done  # end
```

But I want at least a 1 kHz frequency, so a timer is the one, sleep function is not advisable.

How can I about attaining my objective?

Comment: I don't think you will find a trigger with such a high frequency. Instead I would write a small C program that tries to enable/disable the flash light. For the timing use busy waiting and as time source may be [clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,..)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16275444/150978).

Comment: Hi , had a look through your link, but pardon me being a beginner find it difficult to understand it, can you post some other link or a C code that does the same in linux  kernel?

Comment: Sorry Edmund, but this site here is for end-users, not for programmers/developers. But another hint would be to look for [tag:automation] apps like [tag:tasker], which should also be capable of toggling the flashlight.

Comment: OP's own follow-up question: [How to use system timer to run a task periodically on a rooted Redmi Note 5 Pro with Busybox installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246510/44325)

Answer (score 0):

There is Termux and Termux:API.

Termux:

> Android terminal emulator and Linux environment application that works directly with no rooting or setup required. A minimal base system is installed automatically, additional packages are available using the package manager.

Termux:API:

> This addon exposes device functionality as API to command line programs in Termux.

Install both of them from the F-droid website.

Then open up Termux and run `pkg install termux-api nano`

Make a shell script with `nano` using `nano torch.sh`

Use `termux-torch on` and `termux-torch off` to switch on and off the torch.

Also make other edits to fulfill your needs. If you want to do it periodically, use a while loop.

Save and exit the file with Ctrl + X, then type "Y" and enter.

Run `cat torch.sh` to make sure the shell script is edited successfully.

Make sure the shell script is executable by running `chmod +x torch.sh`

Finally, run `./torch.sh`

P.S. You don't even need root to do that lol

Comment: Hi box cpm, a fantastic answer actually, i did as you indicated and i was able to control the torch on and off using the above script, like simply within a while loop, i wrote termux-torch on and termux-torch off(no delay between these 2 statements) , and your method works on even non-rooted phones ! lol :} Amazing!  But there is one problem, even without me introducing a delay between on and off statements, the period is too high like 0.5 seconds, i want period in range of 1 ms, do you have any other solution to tackle this problem!